# How did Kryptonite come to earth?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

If "**Kryptonite**" is ore from Krypton and Krypton was destroyed, then how did this ore come to earth in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice*?

Comment: Just a side note, this is a fairly consistent question/issue throughout the entire Superman mythos - the idea that a planet lightyears away exploded and *any* of it hit Earth is questionable, and when you take into account the fact that every two-bit supervillian in the galaxy seems to have some (when it's convenient to the plot) it just gets ridiculous.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the film Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice, the Kryptonite was evidently contained in the [World Engine](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/World_Engine) seen in the earlier installment; [Man of Steel](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Man_of_Steel).

[image]

As the latest film opens, we see some young children salvaging tech that's fallen outside the exclusion zone and selling it to various (Western) bidders on the beach. This apparently includes a clump of Kryptonite.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think Lex also mentioned that the kryptonite was contained within the device's reactor, but I unfortunately don't have the quote handy.

Comment: @Liesmith - Lex says "A little souvenir from the Kryptonian World Engine" when he refers to the small fragment and that's about it. I'm fairly sure he doesn't talk about what the Kryptonite was being used for.

Comment: Ah, I must've heard "engine" and assumed "reactor".

Comment: A better question would be: If kryptonite comes from Krypton, and is lethal specifically to Kryptonians, how did their species ever evolve on a world chiefly composed of a substance that is inherently deadly to them?  That never made sense to me.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - You may be unaware that the core of the Earth contains vast amounts of uranium, a highly radioactive substance that is inherently deadly to humans. If you blew up the Earth, all that Uranium would just be floating around.

Comment: @Richard - Yeah, but it's mostly in the core.  Krypton (in many depictions) appears to have kryptonite all over the place - they use it in architecture and the like.  Supes even reproduces such a structure on Earth in his Fortress of Solitude.  I guess they must have some other green crystal material that just *looks* like kryptonite.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I think you had misunderstood a bit. Kryptonite makes them mortals and earth by nature makes them immortals. They are not deadly to them it just makes them ordinary mortals and hence can be killed off using them. So all Kryptonians will be mortals in Krypton nothing more.

Comment: @ramb00 - It's not just that though.  Kryptonite on Earth doesn't just make him normal mortal human strength - it weakens him so much he can't even stand up.  (Though they're far from consistent about that - sometimes, he can pick up an entire island made of kryptonite and throw it into the sun - after being impaled through the chest by a spear made of kryptonite...  This is why I don't like Superman in general - they can't even stick to their own rules.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman agreed, somehow I also feel there are lot of hole in Superman and less interesting as a character.

Comment: @Richard no, it doesn't: Uranium is excluded from the iron/nickel core and is found in the mantle.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Superman's mythology has changed at random over the years, but the most reasonable explanation I've seen is that the explosion of Krypton was what actually rendered it radioactive.

Answer (score 11):

In the [original Superman film](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_I_shoot.txt), it was described as being from a meteorite:

> The photo shows an ETHOPIAN FARMER holding a wedge-shaped green rock
>   about a foot long and five inches high. The FARMER grins at the
>   camera. The caption beneath reads: Meteorite Lands near Addis Ababa,
>   Ethiopia, June, 1951.
>
> EVE and OTIS stare at the picture, mystified.
>
> **EVE**
>                 I know I'm going to get rapped in the mouth for saying  this, but - so what?
>
> **LUTHOR** So -what? You mean to us it's just a meteorite? Fair enough.
>   . .
>
> **LUTHOR** But because of its high level of specific  radioactivity - to
>   someone from the planet  Krypton - this substance would be lethal!

The [wiki](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite#History) provides some details on an overview of the explanation with regards to the comic books:

> The amount of kryptonite shown to fall on the Earth in Silver Age
>   stories is too large to have been evenly distributed from the
>   explosion of any reasonably sized planet, so the usual explanation for
>   the large amount that made it to Earth was that the kryptonite and
>   other materials from Krypton were dragged to Earth by the experimental
>   warp drive that brought Superman to Earth.

Also:

> It was possible to artificially create green kryptonite, which the
>   rogue genius Lex Luthor performed on various occasions. However, he
>   rarely needed to do so, as kryptonite was so abundant that many
>   ordinary criminals kept a supply as a precaution against Superman's
>   interference.

Comment: It seems the OP meant *Dawn of Justice*, though.

Comment: Wish OP had bothered to say that then before I wrote this.

Comment: Yeah, it's why I asked, it seemed pretty straightforward in the original

Comment: Yeah. There's so many different versions now, from movie to TV series to comic, it's hard to know where to start. Oh well!

Comment: @AndrewMartin:really sorry

Comment: @DarkArmy: It's fine, don't trouble yourself. Editing questions is both allowed and encouraged, but try not to change the meaning of the questions. Still, I'm glad you've got a good answer!

Comment: Unless you address the film this question actually asks about in any way, this doesn't seem like an appropriate answer at all, though.

Comment: It was written before the OP updated their question to indicate which film they were referring to. Given I'd already written the answer before they'd updated it, I decided to leave it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be explained, but it is creating new ideas and accounts that were never revealed before.  Superman's father put a very large chunk of Kryptonite in the spaceship that took Superman to earth.  Kyptonite only became deadly to Superman in the Earth's atmosphere - and only after he had gone through puberty.  The large chunk was stolen from Superman's earth parents' barn a few years after the spaceship crashed on Earth, and after the chunk was passed around within the underworld, it became apparent to some that the rock was deadly to him.  The rock was broken up into many pieces, but it did not lose its potency.